# Is it beneficial to use ForkJoinPool as usual ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

Let's say I have a code like that:

```
class Foo {
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    public Foo(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        executor.execute(() -> {/* Do important task */});
    }
}
```

Can I gain better performance if instead of passing `ThreadPoolExecutor` in constructor I use `ForkJoinPool`. If yes then why and should I prefer use it in any circumstances instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

**Update 1**

My question is about usage of `ForkJoinPool` through `ExecutorService` API and doesn't suppose recursive task splitting using `ForkJoinPool` specific API.

Comment: It depends on the type of task you are trying to do. Fork-Join pool should be used when you have a task which is composed of many subtasks and you want to join the result of each sub task in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be effective if you use [newWorkStealingPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--)

```
public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
```

> Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.

You can find advantage from this documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

> A **ForkJoinPool** provides the entry point for submissions from non-**ForkJoinTask** clients, as well as management and monitoring operations.
>
> A **ForkJoinPool** differs from other kinds of **ExecutorService** mainly by virtue of employing ***work-stealing***: all threads in the pool attempt to find and execute tasks submitted to the pool and/or created by other active tasks (eventually blocking waiting for work if none exist).
>
> This enables efficient processing when most tasks spawn other subtasks (as do most **ForkJoinTasks**), as well as when many small tasks are submitted to the pool from external clients. Especially when setting **asyncMode** to true in constructors, **ForkJoinPools** may also be appropriate for use with event-style tasks that are never joined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if you have recursive non-blocking tasks.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgsA9cMVf9Q#t=6h5m17s) is great explanation from Cay S. Horstmann from recent Joker conference.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great presentation.